# On identity elements in monoids

Tags: monoid

In the definition of a monoid firstly we should have associativity. What I wonder about is the definition of *the* identity element;

$\exists x \forall y\;\;  x.y=y.x=y $

Which structure do we get if we change the order of quantifiers in the definition? That is;

$\forall y \exists x \;\;  x.y=y.x=y $

Comment: Well, we get something weaker certainly, though still of interest. For example, if $R$ is a ring with unity, then the set of sequences of elements from $R$, which are $0$ from some point, becomes a ring where there is no unit for multiplication, but where the multiplication has the weaker version of a unit you describe here.

Answer (score 2):

In some sense, neither property is that important, because if a semigroup doesn't have an identity you can just add one in (call it $e$) and define $ex = xe = x$ for all $x$.  Then the associative property still holds, and now both of your properties are satisfied.

- **Global identity:** there exists $e$ such that $xe = ex = x$ for all $x$
- **Local identities:** for all $x$ there exists $e_x$ such that $e_x x = x e_x$.

What about semigroups with local identities but *no* global identities?
I'm not sure.  Tobias Kildetoft gives a good example.  Many of the identities will work for multiple elements since $e_x (xyx) = (xyx) e_x = xyx$.  I couldn't find any references on this property being studied or named before.

Comment: Indeed, in the example I mentioned, any finite subset will have a "common identity" (but if the ring $R$ is finite, then no infinite subset will have such a "common identity").

Comment: @Goos Thanks for the answer. As far as I can see the existence of only local identities boils down to this: If all elements of the monoid can be written as $xyx$ then $e_x$ is the global identity. What happens if the premise is not true, I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The structure I asked about seems very much like square matrices. They satisfy associativity and there may be more than one element acting as identity on an element.